# Laravel 9 php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth auth middleware proper error handling

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, middleware

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication API's in Laravel.

I'm using `php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth` from https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-jwt-authentication-laravel-9/

Here's my problem, I'm testing my APIs using POSTMAN, and the auth middleware is working just fine. However, when the user is not authenticated, I get this message on POSTMAN with the code 405 instead of 401.
The message:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
> The GET method is not supported for route api/auth/refresh. Supported
> methods: POST. in file
> E:\Work\practice\react\test-crud-middlewares\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection.php
> on line 122

I implemented an admin middleware that returns a clean error response with the correct status code.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->user() || !$request->user()->isAdmin()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized, you are not an admin.'], 401);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

What should I do to make the auth middleware behave the same and return a proper error?
Here are some screenshots of the response and my `api.php` file:

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try Using post method instead

Comment: Unfortunately, it returned the same output regardless of the method used.